# Array Matrix in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list:

```
[
('2021-09', 29, '3'), 
('2021-09', 249, '4'), 
('2021-09', 162, '5'), 
('2021-10', 16, '3'), 
('2021-10', 392, '4'), 
('2021-10', 255, '5'), 
('2021-11', 9, '3'), 
('2021-11', 321, '4'), 
('2021-11', 240, '5'), 
('2021-12', 6, '3'), 
('2021-12', 332, '4'), 
('2021-12', 205, '5'), 
('2022-01', 1, '1'), 
('2022-01', 8, '3'), 
('2022-01', 304, '4'), 
('2022-01', 221, '5'), 
('2022-02', 6, '3'), 
('2022-02', 321, '4'), 
('2022-02', 262, '5'),
('2022-03', 9, '3'),
('2022-03', 359, '4'), ('2022-03', 284, '5'), ('2022-04', 7, '3'), ('2022-04', 350, '4'), ('2022-04', 331, '5'), ('2022-05', 9, '3'), ('2022-05', 419, '4'), ('2022-05', 301, '5'), ('2022-06', 2, '3'), ('2022-06', 427, '4'), ('2022-06', 348, '5'), ('2022-07', 7, '3'), ('2022-07', 458, '4'), ('2022-07', 294, '5'), ('2022-08', 2, '3'), ('2022-08', 437, '4'), ('2022-08', 270, '5'), ('2022-09', 15, '4'), ('2022-09', 5, '5')]
```

For your reference:

```
('2021-09', 29, '3')
```

- `'2021-09'` is Year-month
- 29 is number of incidents in the month
- `'3'` is Severity/Priority (`Severity1`, `Severity2`, `Severity3`, ...)

I want output like the below:

```
[
  {
    'Dates': ['2021-09', '2021-10', '2021-11', '2021-12', '2022-01', '2022-02', '2022-03', '2022-04', '2022-05', '2022-06', '2022-07', '2022-08', '2022-09'],
    'Severity1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #('2022-01', 1, '1')
    'Severity2': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], # there is no incident of priority 2, so all should be 0
    'Severity3': [29, 16, 9, 6, 8, 6, 9, 7, 9, 2, 7, 2, 0], # ('2021-09', 29, '3'), ('2021-10', 16, '3'), ('2021-11', 9, '3'), ('2021-12', 6, '3'), ('2022-01', 8, '3'), and so on for the list above
    'Severity4': [249, 392, 321, 332, 304, 321, 359, 350, 419, 427, 458, 437, 15]}), #('2021-09', 249, '4'), ('2021-10', 392, '4'), ('2021-11', 321, '4'), and so on from the list above
  }
]
```

I want to create a graph like below :

[image]

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I tried defaultdict(lambda: []) and for loop, but no success.. is there any other way i shall try?

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've done, and what result it gets. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: One method might be to build a dict of `{date: {severity: count}` then you could iterate through it and append to multiple lists at once.